# Efficient way of generating random integers within a range in Julia

Tags: random, integer, julia

I'm doing MC simulations and I need to generate random integers within a range between `1` and a variable upper limit `n_mol`

The specific Julia function for doing this is `rand(1:n_mol)` where `n_mol` is an integer that changes with every MC iteration. The problem is that doing it this is slow... (possibly an issue to open for Julia developers). So, instead of using that particular function call, I thought about generating a random float in [0,1) multiply it by `n_mol` and then get the integer part of the result: `int(rand()*n_mol)` the problem now is that `int()` rounds up so I could end up with numbers between `0` and `n_mol`, and I can't get `0`... so the solution I'm using for the moment is using `ifloor` and add a `1`, `ifloor(rand()*n_mol)+1`, which considerably faster that the first, but slower than the second.

```
function t1(N,n_mol)
    for i = 1:N
        rand(1:n_mol)
    end
end

function t2(N,n_mol)
    for i = 1:N
        int(rand()*n_mol)
    end
end

function t3(N,n_mol)
    for i = 1:N
        ifloor(rand()*n_mol)+1
    end
end


@time t1(1e8,123456789)
@time t2(1e8,123456789)
@time t3(1e8,123456789)


elapsed time: 3.256220849 seconds (176 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.482307467 seconds (176 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.975422095 seconds (176 bytes allocated)
```

So, is there any way of doing this faster with speeds near the second test?
It's important because the MC simulation goes for more than 1e10 iterations.
The result has to be an integer because it will be used as an index of an array.

Comment: Have you looked at Julia's MCMC library, Lora.jl?

Comment: Be very careful implementing your own shortcuts.  I'm not a random number expert, but I know that you can easily introduce biases by modifying random numbers.  Both `t2` and `t3` require that `n_mol ≪ maxintfloat(Float64)`.  And `t2` will be slightly biased towards even numbers on Julia 0.4 since it uses ["unbiased" rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) by default (ironic, no? again, this effect will be greater as `n_mol` increases).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rand(r::Range) code is quite fast, given the following two considerations. First, julia calls a 52 bit rng twice to obtain random integers and a 52 bit rng once to obtain random floats, that gives with some book keeping a factor 2.5. A second thing is that

```
(rand(Uint) % k)
```

is only evenly distributed between 0 to k-1, if k is a power of 2. This is taken care of with rejection sampling, this explains more or less the remaining additional cost.

If speed is extremely important you can use a simpler random number generator as Julia and ignore those issues. For example with a linear congruential generator without rejection sampling

```
function lcg(old) 
    a = unsigned(2862933555777941757)
    b = unsigned(3037000493)
    a*old + b
end

function randfast(k, x::Uint)
    x = lcg(x)
    1 + rem(x, k) % Int, x
end

function t4(N, R)
    state = rand(Uint)
    for i = 1:N
        x, state = randfast(R, state)
    end
end
```

But be careful, if the range is (really) big.

```
m = div(typemax(Uint),3)*2

julia> mean([rand(1:m)*1.0 for i in 1:10^7])
6.148922790091841e18

julia> m/2
6.148914691236517e18
```

but (!)

```
julia> mean([(rand(Uint) % m)*1.0 for i in 1:10^7])
5.123459611164573e18

julia> 5//12*tm
5.124095576030431e18
```

Comment: This looks promising. I sort of simplificated it the calculations a little and I'm getting almost an order of maginuted of better results that my `t2` function. The range shouldn't be larger than 1e12 so its pretty safe to use. I'm not sure if rejection sampling should an issue for me or not, but I'll check it out and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in 0.4, `int()` is deprecated, and you're aske to use `round()` instead.

```
function t2(N,n_mol)
  for i = 1:N
    round(rand()*n_mol)
  end
end
```

gives 0.27 seconds on my machine (using Julia 0.4).

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know `int()` is deprecated in 0.4... using `round()` in 0.3.11 is much slower for some reason. Maybe it was changed in 0.4. Still can't really use it because if `rand()*n_mol` is `<0.5` it will be rounded to 0 and I can't use that.

Comment: try using `ceil(Int,rand()*n_mol)`: this will round up, and return an integer type

Comment: @SimonByrne: `rand()` returns a floating point number in the range `[0, 1)`.  It'd be a 1 in a quadrillion shot, but it could potentially return 0.  If my wimpy laptop were to continuously generate random numbers with `rand()`, it might happen about once a month.

Comment: @SimonByrne I tried doing ceil but it takes 2x the time from my test 2 (at least in 0.3.11) Thanks!